# Accepting multiple connections from clients on a serversocket

Tags: java, serversocket

I just started using Sockets, and for my current project I need to be able to control my program from a client, however if my project-partner wants use his client at the same time, the server doesn't send him the "You are connected" message as shown in the  connection class. So I assume the server doesn't accept mutiple clients at the same time. I have tried using a Thread of the class Connection, but that also doesn't send the message "You are connected" to the second Client. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Listener extends Thread{

private ServerSocket server;
private int PORT;
public boolean running;

public Listener(int port){
    try{
        this.PORT = port;
        this.server = new ServerSocket(PORT,10);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not create serverSocket...");
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    this.running = true;
    try{
        waitForConnection();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Could not accept connection request..");
        run();
    }


}
public void dispose(){
    try{
        System.out.println("DISPOSE");
        running = false;
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Could not close ServerSocket");
    }
}
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    while(running){
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        Socket client = server.accept();
        Runnable connection = new Connection(client);
        new Thread(connection).start();
    }
}       
}
```

This is the Thread I'm using to have multiple users connect at the same time:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import java.net.Socket;

public class Connection extends Thread {
     Socket connection;
     private ObjectOutputStream output;
     private ObjectInputStream input;
     private boolean running;

     public Connection(Socket connect){
          this.connection = connect;
          try {
              setupStreams();
              whileListening();
          } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("could not connect to: "+ connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }
}

public void dispose(){
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
        running = false;
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

private void whileListening(){
    String message = "You are connected! ";
    sendMessage(message);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            checkMessage(message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            sendMessage("tf did you send? ");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            dispose();
            run();
        }
    }while(!message.equals("Client - END") && running == true);
}

private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
}

private  void sendMessage(String message){
    try {
        output.writeObject("Server - " + message+"\n");
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkMessage(String text){
        //check the message
}
}
```

EDIT: Addittional information

Before the first client connects, the server console says "Waiting for connection", then when the first client connects, the client console says "You are connected" and, when a second client connects, the console is black, when I close the first client, the second client console says "You are connected" and the server console says "Waiting for connection", then if I close the second client aswell, the server console says "Waiting for connection" again.

Comment: You need to use non blocking IO

Comment: `System.out.println("Waiting for connection");`do you see that text again before your friend tries to connect again?

Comment: @Soulan I made an edit in the question, I hope that explains what happens.

Comment: @redFIVE like using a ServerSocketChannel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor of the `public class Connection extends Thread` you do this `whileListening()`stuff, so your constructor never ends, you need to override the `run()` function and do that there

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            whileListening();
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

like so, it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe it was such a minor mistake, anyway it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

I think you must accept first, after that you start the thread.

For example, let's suppose something like this

1. in your main class, you get the ServerSocketFactory and then the ServerSocket.
2. then, inside an (endless) loop, you wait for a new Socket returned by the ServerSocket.accept()
3. Only after that, you start your thread

Here's an example from a SSLServerSocket, which is pretty much the same logic (consider it a pseudo-code)

```
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    (...)
    SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
    SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(portNumber);
    while (listening) {
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
        log.info("Serving");
        new SimpleSSLServerSocketThread(c).start();
    }
```